# How can I extend FlowLayout so components are sized to take up as much space as possible?

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a GUI in Java using Swing.

FlowLayout sizes objects to their preferred sizes.  If the width of the container is exceeded, FlowLayout creates a new line.

[image: A short label]
[image]

Other layout managers resize components so that they fill up all available space.  I'd like to do the same thing here, so that the text field automatically fills up all the available space on the top line in the first example, and fills up the whole of the second line in the second example.  The layout wraps when there is not enough room to fit in the label and the text field without the text field being smaller than its preferred size.

Is there an SDK layout manager that provides both these features - wrapping and automatic resizing of components?  Or will I have to extend FlowLayout?  Would it be easier to implement the wrapping in a different layout manager instead?

Comment: Don’t try to extend a class that is not designed to be extended. You would end up doing code consisting of workarounds only and have to re-implement the entire logic anyway. You have to implement your own LayoutManager.

Comment: `Is there an SDK layout manager that provides both these features - wrapping and automatic` - No. Usually people design the form with label/text field pairs and place each group on its own line. You can use the GridBagLayout for this.

Comment: @camickr So how would I do that for a single label/text pair, as in this example?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the requirement. You won't be able to do this with any layout manager that I know of. You can write your own. It really should be too difficult since it looks like you have a very strict requirements.

Answer (score 0):

BoxLayout should work for you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: BoxLayout doesn't wrap components.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 My mistake, misread what you wanted. Try http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/.